# XCode 14.2: The CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I was using cmake to generate the xcode project. I had cmake 3.21.4 and Xcode 14.2 installed. Then I just created **an empty CMakeList.txt** and in the same folder, I tried this command:

```
cmake -G Xcode
```

On a normal Mac, this should be succesful. But on My Mac I met with:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
```

It seems that cmake can not identify the AppleCLang.

I have verified that "xcode-select -p" returned "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer", which was correct.

I looked into the CMakeError.log and it said
"error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Command-line Tool'. (in target 'CompilerIdC' from project 'CompilerIdC')"

I think this error was the cause of the unknown compiler. But I didn't know how to resolve the problem. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: @DrewDormann As far as I can see, this post shows that the asker followed the steps in the top answer post there. Why didn't you just edit instead of commenting?

Comment: @DrewDormann It seems that the question is a similar problem on Windows, which is a bit different.

Comment: Very well.  I won't distract with my suggested link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more information about my problem.